# Glassfish 3.1 - How to configure JMS on multiple domains?

Tags: jms, glassfish-3, multiple-domains

Due to classloading issues I need to deploy an ear and a war in separate domains in the same instance of Glassfish 3.1.1.  The war sends messages to a queue and and MDB in the ear should receive and action it.

The JMS is set up in the domains thusly:

**domain1 default_JMS_host** (server-config | Java Message Service | JMS Hosts):

```
Type = local
Host = localhost
Port = 7676
```

**domain2 default_JMS_host** (server-config | Java Message Service | JMS Hosts):

```
Type = remote
Host = localhost
Port = 7676
```

Originally I had the port on domain2 set to 5076, but that caused connection refused exceptions on domain startup.

With this setup everything seems to load fine (no errors in domain2 server.log) but it doesn't pick up the messages put in the queue by the war file.  I have confirmed that the messages are being put in the queue by the war using the command:

```
/<glassfish>/mq/bin/imqcmd list dst -b localhost:7676 -u admin
```

I have tried searching for how to set up JMS with multiple domains in the same Glassfish instance, but haven't found anything useful.  Can someone point me to a good resource on how to set this up?

Comment: I already answered this question inside java.net forum:
Follow this discussion:
http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/how-configure-jms-multiple-domains

Comment: Hi, yes you did answer my question there.  If you would post an answer on this thread, I will gladly accept it!

Comment: @sdoca, can you post answer for this question from Gustavo

Comment: @Bagdat Not really, it was a fairly long forum discussion.  Here's a link to a cached page of the forum: http://glassfish.10926.n7.nabble.com/How-to-configure-JMS-on-multiple-domains-td3312.html

Answer (score 0):

portbase info also could be usefull for this questuion:

https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/flexible_glassfish_domain_creation_using

so, for several domains you cah set up the portbase with one JMS port per domain